# Using org-protocol with a floating capture window?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I have recently [found a way to have a floating capture window](http://www.windley.com/archives/2010/12/capture_mode_and_emacs.shtml), with this setting I can create a floating capture window using:

```
emacsclient -n -e '(make-capture-frame)'
```

My knowledge of elisp and org-mode internals being close to 0, I did not find a way to have the same behaviour via the org-protocol. What I would like is that when a call happen using the org-protocol, I have a nice floating capture window in front of me.

Note that I'm not attach to use this specific code to create a floating capture window, but that is my current starting point.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```el
;;;
;; Capture floating frame
;;
;; taken from: http://www.windley.com/archives/2010/12/capture_mode_and_emacs.shtml
;;;

(defadvice org-capture-finalize
    (after delete-capture-frame activate)
  "Advise capture-finalize to close the frame"
  (if (equal "capture" (frame-parameter nil 'name))
      (delete-frame)))

(defadvice org-capture-destroy
    (after delete-capture-frame activate)
  "Advise capture-destroy to close the frame"
  (if (equal "capture" (frame-parameter nil 'name))
      (delete-frame)))

;; make the frame contain a single window. by default org-capture
;; splits the window.
(add-hook 'org-capture-mode-hook
          'delete-other-windows)

(defadvice org-switch-to-buffer-other-window
  (after supress-window-splitting activate)
  "Delete the extra window if we're in a capture frame"
  (if (equal "capture" (frame-parameter nil 'name))
      (delete-other-windows)))

(defun make-capture-frame ()
  "Create a new frame and run org-capture."
  (interactive)
  (make-frame '((name . "capture")
                (width . 120)
                (height . 15)))
  (select-frame-by-name "capture")
  (setq word-wrap 1)
  (setq truncate-lines nil)
  (org-capture))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have devised a "hacky" solution.

I have rewrite the `make-capture-frame` to support an optional argument, and directly call `org-protocol-capture` with this argument if it exist.

```el
(defun make-capture-frame (&optional capture-url)
  "Create a new frame and run org-capture."
  (interactive)
  (make-frame '((name . "capture")
                (width . 120)
                (height . 15)))
  (select-frame-by-name "capture")
  (setq word-wrap 1)
  (setq truncate-lines nil)
  (if capture-url (org-protocol-capture capture-url) (org-capture)))
```

Thus I can call emacs like that:

```
emacsclient -n -e '(make-capture-frame)'
```

or

```
emacsclient -n -e '(make-capture-frame-test "x/test/test")'
```

`x/test/test` being the org-protocol url without the `org-protocol://capture://` part.

While this is working, it is not as generic as the org-protocol allow. Thus to support any new subprotocol I have to add a specific function.

Comment: Without any other proposition, I'll validate mine even if it's not a perfect one...

Comment: What is `make-capture-frame-test`?

Comment: Sorry I have no clue anymore... I am not using org-mode/emacs since almost 6 months, since my trial of this editors. Maybe a typo/misscopy?